# SQL injection attempt on my server

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-injection

I know a little about SQL injections and URL decode, but can someone who's more of an expert than me on this matter take a look at the following string and tell me what exactly it's trying to do?

Some kid from Beijing a couple weeks ago tried a number of injections like the one below.

> %27%20and%20char(124)%2Buser%2Bchar(124)=0%20and%20%27%27=%27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's making a guess about the sort of SQL statement that the form data is being substituted into, and assuming that it will be poorly sanitised at some step along the road. Consider a program talking to an SQL server (Cish code purely for example):

```
fprintf(sql_connection, "SELECT foo,bar FROM users WHERE user='%s';");
```

However, with the above string, the SQL server sees:

```
SELECT foo,bar FROM users WHERE user='' and char(124)+user+char(124)=0 and ''='';
```

Whoops! That wasn't what you intended. What happens next depends on the database back-end and whether or not you've got verbose error reporting turned on.

It's quite common for lazy web developers to enable verbose error reporting unconditionally for all clients and to not turn it off. (Moral: only enable detailed error reporting for a very tight trusted network, if at all.) Such an error report typically contains some useful information about the structure of the database which the attacker can use to figure out where to go next.

Now consider the username `'; DESCRIBE TABLE users; SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE 'a'='`. And so it goes on... There are a few different strategies here depending on exactly how the data comes out. SQL injection toolkits exist which can automate this process and attempt to automatically dump out the entire contents of a database via an unsecured web interface. [Rafal Los's blog post](http://www.communities.hp.com/securitysoftware/blogs/rafal/archive/2010/02/25/a-big-case-of-oops.aspx) contains a little more technical insight.

You're not limited to the theft of data, either; if you can insert arbitrary SQL, well, the [obligatory xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/327/) illustrates it better than I can.

Comment: It should be noted that not every database allows for query stacking.  For instance mysql5 introduced it,  but mysql_query() still only accepts 1 query.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find detailed info here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilcar/archive/2008/03/15/anatomy-of-a-sql-injection-incident-part-2-meat.aspx

> These lines are double-encoded -- the
>   first set of encoded characters, which
>   would be translated by IIS, are
>   denoted by %XX.  For example, %20 is a
>   space.  The second set aren't meant to
>   be translated until they get to the
>   SQL Server and they use the char(xxx)
>   function in SQL.

Comment: I'm familiar with char(). What's this string aiming at?

Answer (score 2):

```
' and char(124)+user+char(124)=0 and ''='
```

that's strange..however, make sure you escape strings so there will be no sql injections

Comment: It's all been sanitized by a class before it went to the database, so I'm reasonably sure nothing got in.

Comment: I'd still like to understand it :)

Comment: even better than messing about escaping strings, just use bound parameters in your sql. it's super easy and it always protects you.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have covered what's going on, so I'm going to take a moment to get on my high-horse and strongly suggest that if you're not already (I suspect not from a comment below) that you *use parameterized queries*.  They literally make you immune to SQL injection because they cause parameters and the query to be transmitted completely separately.  There's also potential performance benefits, yadda yadda, etc.

But seriously, do it.